# How to handle links that open in new tabs in react native web view?

Tags: android, react-native, payment-gateway

I am trying to convert my e-commerce website into an app using react native webview. But I am facing some issue in payment gateway.

Here is how things work in my website :

place order-> checkout page -> click pay now button -> payment api opens a new tab for confirmation and then returns back to website.

Here is what happens in webview :

place order -> checkout page -> click pay now button -> app asks whether you want to leave app or not -> select leave app -> blank page in browser

It is not showing the payment confirmation window. Also, is there a way to open that confirmation window inside the app itself ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mind me asking which payment gateway you are trying to integrate? I've integrated Chase and Stripe into React Native and Ionic apps so I might be able to help if it's either of those.

Comment: I am using Razorpay for this project.

Answer (score 0):

React Native In App Browser can open a web view inside your app. https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser

I've used it for a few apps and it's worked well.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for replying!

Comment: @SuryaMahla, Been a long time since you have asked this question. Can you post the answer, hoping that you have found the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @PratikAdhikari, unfortunately I was not able to find any solution at that time so the team decided to move on with a different payment gateway whose flow was compatible with our project.